# How to use callbacks in Activity

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie in Android developing and i try to understand how to use callbacks in interfaces.

I am use ["Color-pick-preference"](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference) library in my app. I need it to change different settings, for example background color. And i want to change in runtime, without refresh activities.

This is how i do it now:

Color-picker-preference have three main classes:

ColorPickerView (as I understand it show color panel and send user choise via callback to ColorPickerDialog)

ColorPickerDialog (this class show preferebce dialog window  includes color panel, submit color button etc. And send user choise data further in ColorPickerPreference)

and ColorPicerPreference wich save user choise in Shared Preferences.

I described very superficially, if you'll excuse me.

**Parts of these three files**

*ColorPickerView*

```
***



***
private OnColorChangedListener mListener;


***
public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    public void onColorChanged(int color);
}

***

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    boolean update = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            mStartTouchPoint = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            update = moveTrackersIfNeeded(event);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            update = moveTrackersIfNeeded(event);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            mStartTouchPoint = null;

            update = moveTrackersIfNeeded(event);

            break;

    }

    if (update) {

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onColorChanged(Color.HSVToColor(mAlpha, new float[]{mHue, mSat, mVal}));
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

***

public void setOnColorChangedListener(OnColorChangedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

***

public void setColor(int color, boolean callback) {

    int alpha = Color.alpha(color);

    float[] hsv = new float[3];

    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);

    mAlpha = alpha;
    mHue = hsv[0];
    mSat = hsv[1];
    mVal = hsv[2];

    if (callback && mListener != null) {
        mListener.onColorChanged(Color.HSVToColor(mAlpha, new float[]{mHue, mSat, mVal}));
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

*ColorPickerDialog*

```
***

public class ColorPickerDialog
    extends
    Dialog
    implements
    ColorPickerView.OnColorChangedListener,
    View.OnClickListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener ...

***

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

***

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    public void onColorChanged(int color);
}

***

 private void setUp(int color) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_color_picker, null);
    mLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    mOrientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    setContentView(mLayout);

    setTitle(R.string.dialog_color_picker);

    mColorPicker = (ColorPickerView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.color_picker_view);
    mOldColor = (ColorPickerPanelView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.old_color_panel);
    mNewColor = (ColorPickerPanelView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_color_panel);

    mHexVal = (EditText) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.hex_val);
    mHexVal.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    mHexDefaultTextColor = mHexVal.getTextColors();

    mHexVal.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                String s = mHexVal.getText().toString();
                if (s.length() > 5 || s.length() < 10) {
                    try {
                        int c = ColorPickerPreference.convertToColorInt(s.toString());
                        mColorPicker.setColor(c, true);
                        mHexVal.setTextColor(mHexDefaultTextColor);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        mHexVal.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                } else {
                    mHexVal.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    ((LinearLayout) mOldColor.getParent()).setPadding(
            Math.round(mColorPicker.getDrawingOffset()),
            0,
            Math.round(mColorPicker.getDrawingOffset()),
            0
    );

    mOldColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mNewColor.setOnClickListener(this);
    mColorPicker.setOnColorChangedListener(this);
    mOldColor.setColor(color);
    mColorPicker.setColor(color, true);

}

***

@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {

    mNewColor.setColor(color);

    if (mHexValueEnabled)
        updateHexValue(color);


}

***

public void setOnColorChangedListener(OnColorChangedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

*ColorPickerPreference*

```
public class ColorPickerPreference
    extends
    Preference
    implements
    Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener,
    ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener ...

***

@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    if (isPersistent()) {
        persistInt(color);
    }
    mValue = color;
    setPreviewColor();
    try {
        getOnPreferenceChangeListener().onPreferenceChange(this, color);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
    notifyChanged();
}

***

protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    mDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(getContext(), mValue);
    mDialog.setOnColorChangedListener(this);
    if (mAlphaSliderEnabled) {
        mDialog.setAlphaSliderVisible(true);
    }
    if (mHexValueEnabled) {
        mDialog.setHexValueEnabled(true);
    }
    if (state != null) {
        mDialog.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
    mDialog.show();
}
```

And what i try to do in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

public ColorPickerDialog cpd;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    Integer id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_action_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cpd = new ColorPickerDialog(this,Color.BLACK);
    cpd.setOnColorChangedListener(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    RelativeLayout main_scroll_view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_rel_layout);
    System.out.println("AIM ALIVE!");
    main_scroll_view.setBackgroundColor(color);

}


}
```

But when i change color in ColorPickerPreference widget -nothing happens. the background color does not change and my System.out.println does not work ?

Sorry for chaotic presentation and thank you for your answers.

**I too myself more of a challenge) Solved the problem by simply adding the onResume method in Mainactivity and check the Shared Preference and then setting the background color in the resulting value.**

Comment: Too much code; didn't read.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare the action so you could show/open the dialog?

Comment: In SettingActivity using headers.

Answer (score 0):

SettingActivity

```
***

 public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    PrefernceAnimation pa;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String settings = getArguments().getString("settings");
        if ("colors".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_fragment_colors);
        } else if ("sounds".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_fragment_sounds);
        }
          else if ("animation".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_fragment_animation);

        }

    }

}
```

and preference_headers.xml

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<header
    android:fragment="com.dosomeweb.mika.babypic.SettingActivity$SettingsFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_main_title_colors"
    android:summary="@string/pref_main_summery_colors">
    <extra
        android:name="settings"
        android:value="colors"/>


</header>

<header
    android:fragment="com.dosomeweb.mika.babypic.SettingActivity$SettingsFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_main_title_sounds"
    android:summary="@string/pref_main_summery_sounds">
    <extra
        android:name="settings"
        android:value="sounds"/>



</header>

<header
    android:fragment="com.dosomeweb.mika.babypic.SettingActivity$SettingsFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_main_title_animation"
    android:summary="@string/pref_main_summery_animation">
<extra
    android:name="settings"
    android:value="animation"/>
</header>
```

just in case prference_fragment_colors.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<net.margaritov.preference.colorpicker.ColorPickerPreference
    android:key="pref_bg_color"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_layout_bg_color"
    android:summary="@string/pref_summary_layout_bg_color"
    android:defaultValue="@color/colorAccent"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating so many different interface? Why not use 1 interface and link it all together since the callback have the same parameter.

Comment: Because all interfaces are created in the library ColorPickerPreference , I wouldn't want to edit this code, it is still too difficult for me. I would just use the interface OnColorChangedListener from there in my MainActivity. But it's not working.

Comment: Your CPD is not calling the interface of MainActivity.